# Store animated gif into localStorage and load it later

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In javascript I have a routine where I save gif image from URL to localStorage. On next page reload I check if there is something in localStorage and if YES - I display that gif from localStorage rather than loading it from URL. It works well!

I used this script:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

The problem is that it won't work for animated gifs. The problem is (at least I think so) because on first page load gif is loaded in canvas element which is probably only 2d and one frame therefore gif saved to localStorage is static and not animated. When I read it from localStorage and display it, it will be static.

How could I save animated gif to localStorage and when I load it and display on page it would still be animating?

Comment: Why not let browser caching do this? And you can save the link to the animated gif to local storage rather than the actual gif...

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. After a while gif wasn't cached anymore (really depends on browsers, settings, cloud flare) so I can't use it. I need to show a default image when network is down and I can only do that if I load it from localStorage. I know what you mean - I had img1 in hidden div and on network down I did   img2.src = img1.src but it didn't work after a while (would be best solution!). So I am trying to save animated gif (and load it later!). Maybe this is possible with some kind of blob thing but I don't know.

Comment: No you can hide the animated gif with css and use js to show it when you know the network is down; don't need to use localstorage for this.

Comment: I tried that but when network is down and I do img2.src = hidden_image.src sometimes browser shows broken image (because it didn't try to load it from cache - hidden animated gif). For some reason it went to reload it but since network is off, it failed.

Comment: If the network is down your site won't work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I was dreaming about a solution tonight. How could I not see it. I should load image1 (when loading the website - means internet is ON) then when I detect no network in javascript, I should simple display this same image1 over all screen (just make it visible) and I don't have to do any assignment which didn't work (image2=image1). Will try to do this today.